# How can I express "Get ready people, now I'll give a little bit of information about the person/thing" succinctly in English?

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary

In my native language, when an additional information needed in support of the subject we talk about, we do it in the following way

> In the absence of Marty, Alberto will stand in for him. I should **open brackets** for Alberto. He has worked in the similar industry for 30 years and he ....
>
> The UK and Ireland pledged to protect the deep ties of family and friendship. I'll **open brackets** for Ireland. They left the UK after 1921

We use "**open brackets**" term to say that "Get ready people, now I'll give a little bit of information about the person/thing."

Is there a native/natural way of doing that in English? Because I know that "open brackets" is not used in English in the way I used

Comment: *First you tell 'em what you're going to tell 'em. Then you tell 'em. Then you tell 'em what you told 'em.* Why not just ***tell them*** whatever "brief background info" you have in mind? If it's just an "open brackets, parenthetical **aside**", maybe all you're *really* doing is telling the audience they can switch off for a few seconds, because what you're about to tell them is just peripheral / parenthetical background stuff, not the "meat" of whatever you're saying. Possible English "equivalents" include *A little bit of background about XXX...*

Comment: "A little bit of background about XXX..." is too formal. It doesn't go with the flow when you're talking. Your suggestion could be used in a formal document.

Comment: As a native speaker, "A little bit of background about..." does not strike me as formal *at all*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key phrase for this situation is "by the way". It means, I'm about to tell you something that isn't directly the cause or result of what I just told you, but more a (maybe weakly) related fact about something we just talked about.

To fit it into your examples,

> In the absence of Marty, Alberto will stand in for him. By the way, Alberto has worked in the similar industry for 30 years and he...

(Note: "by the way" is a bit informal, so you might not use it when presenting an important fact like this to a customer or client)

> The UK and Ireland pledged to protect the deep ties of family and friendship. By the way, Ireland left the UK after 1921

A more realistic example of the kind of informal situation you might use this,

> I'll introduce you to John later. By the way, John was best man at my wedding, so he'll know most of the other people at the party already.